# C Macro Preprocessor to include a number in string

Tags: c, macros, decimal, c-preprocessor

I would like to insert arbitrary control codes `x` into a string but use decimal numbers rather than hex (`\ux`) or oct (`\0x`). To use a pointless but immediately understandable example, I would be happy to have a macro, say CC, so that I could form a string as:

```
// Decimal 10 and 13 are ASCII LF and CR resp.
char mystring[] = "This is line 1" CC(10) CC(13) "This is line 2";
```

[Ultimately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77176899/c-macro-preprocessor-to-include-a-number-in-string#comment136056100_77176951), this code would be used with other non-standard functions/behaviours on custom hardware.

Comment: Since there isn't a way to embed escaped characters in a string using decimal escape sequences— only octal or hex — you can't do what you want (certainly not sanely).

Comment: There's no easy way to do it, and you shouldn't do it. Just use `\r\n`. That's what everyone else expects, and what you'll see in others' code.

Comment: From your comment to the answer below: "_control codes within the display data sent over a slow wireless connection_" and based on the sample string above... Look into "byte pair encoding" or, perhaps, another form of data compression (eg: a canonical Huffman encoding on both ends.) It seems your objective is to maximise throughput over a slow connection that has processing power available on both ends. A clear statement of needs would save everyone's time.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and focus on the actual problem, which appears to be sending strings over a slow wireless link - not creating exotic escape sequences in C strings. Maybe you should ask about how to do that best instead - it sounds like a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com. I can share some experience on that topic.

Comment: You've accepted the answer from @chqrlie. Just a suggestion: Rather than build a homespun protocol limited to only multiple SP's, extend it now to include the character to be multiplied. The tickertape LED display seen at the mall, today, included stretches of multiple asterisks, and multiple equals, too... No time like the present for feature creep...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no generic way to do this for decimal numbers, but if there are a limited number of codes, you can use token pasting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CC_13  "\x0D"
#define CC_10  "\x0A"

#define CONCAT(a, b)  a ## b
#define CC(n) CONCAT(CC_, n)

int main(void) {
    // Decimal 13 and 10 are ASCII CR and LF resp.
    char mystring[] = "This is line 1" CC(13) CC(10) "This is line 2";

    // simple macros are supported too
    #define CR 13
    #define LF 10

    printf("%s" CC(CR) CC(LF), mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

The macro `CC` can be used with numbers and simple macros, as long as the corresponding `CC_xxx` macro is defined as a string constant.  If this definition is missing, you will get a (somewhat cryptic) error message.

If your goal is to embed control bytes, the above should be fine albeit a bit overkill as you could use the `CC_xxx` macros directly.

From extra information provided in comments, you seem to want to embed binary data inside the string constants as arguments for inline commands, themselves specified as control codes: it would be cumbersome to use the above trick for this and specifying numbers outside the range 1..255 may cause problems as you will embed null bytes in these strings that might be misinterpreted.

I suggest you pass these arguments as a string of digits to be parsed at runtime, inside the destination device. Here is an example:

```
#define STR(n)  #n
#define WHITESPACE(n)  "\x1B" STR(n) "F"

char sentence[] = "A big space between here" WHITESPACE(30) "and here."
```

You can send this string to the device and the device handler will parse an optional numeric argument between the escape byte and the `F` (for forward) to move forward by a number of pixels.  Using escape sequences is just an example, you can use a whatever convention suits you best, but it allows for easy string construction on the server side using `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // Slide in a welcome message
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        char buf[80];
        // CR moves the cursor the beginning of the line
        // ESC K erases the rest of the line
        // ESC n F moves the cursor right by n pixels
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "\r\033K\033%dFHello world!", 100 - i);
        send_device(buf);
        usleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'd like any number as I'd like to use the values as arguments for control codes. Eg: have a control code `WHITESPACE` appended with a number to insert a whitespace of a number of pixels.


`char sentence[] = "A big space between here" WHITESPACE CC(30) "and here."`

Comment: @Kay: there are strong limitations but I'm afraid there is no generic solution in C.  Another approach is to embed the argument in ASCII: `#define WHITESPACE(n) 
 "\x01(" #n ")"` used as `char sentence[] = "A big space between here" WHITESPACE(30) "and here."` and convert the number at runtime from digits instead of reading bytes.

Comment: And here I thought supporting code obfuscation was something SO discouraged.

Comment: @chqrlie That's a smart idea - loses some efficiencies but does accomplish the purpose that others here refuse to grasp. Thank you.

Comment: @Kay What you are seeking could be implemented by hacking the source code for `printf()`... Go ahead and be non-standard... Gnu has anticipated you...

Comment: I am working on a small embedded system with a custom LED matrix display. There's nothing standard here and including control codes within the display data sent over a slow wireless connection would be handy.

Comment: @Kay Don't elaborate your needs in comments buried under an answer. Edit the question and describe your situation where all expect to see it. What's the point of having people think you'll be using `printf()` when that is not appropriate? It's hard to **grasp** what is not even suggested in your question.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Point taken rusty. Question edited.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this counts as a sane solution or not — but it should work.  There could be a lot of CC_### macros around if you need to cover an entire 8-bit code set.